# How to create shadow password from a C program

Tags: c, linux

Function `crypt()` returns a string like `TyVkFBglLfEGw`, when on my Ubuntu machine all passwords are in form like 
`$6$Ty8Ew9/O$V/ck4Apc7VOOqobhenO5.f6ccsVdCpQy5H6fyuNzCaDG.LxFnUWKHOobkpRQQtl.1cFG8BLAdfWjNbLiSxKXF/`

I think my machine uses SHA512 algorithm. How can I create hashed strings like in `/etc/shadow` file from a C program?

Comment: Are you sure that you mean encrypt?  Nothing beginning with SHA will encrypt anything.  These are "Secure Hash Algorithms."  You can *hash* with them, perhaps even adding a salt... Is that what you mean?

Comment: sha belongs to integrity hashing. there is no encryption involved. in fact, considering the bit length, it's almost impossible to find 2 string sharing the same hash in SHA512.

Comment: The sample encrypted password you posted is `SHA-512` using salt `$6$Ty8Ew9/O$`.  `crypt()` will return the encrypted password without salt.

Comment: Also see [How should someone create an encrypted password for /etc/shadow?](http://serverfault.com/q/87874) on Server Fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [man page for crypt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html); specifically the piece about Glibc notes, it mentions the following:

```
The glibc2 version of this function supports additional encryption
algorithms.

If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$"
followed by a string terminated by "$":

      $id$salt$encrypted
```

then instead of using the DES machine, id identifies the encryption
   method used and this then determines how the rest of the password
   string is interpreted.  The following values of id are supported:

```
      ID  | Method
      ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
      1   | MD5
      2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
          | Linux distributions)
      5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
      6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
```

So $5$salt$encrypted is an SHA-256 encoded password and
   $6$salt$encrypted is an SHA-512 encoded one.

this means that you should pass in a string as salt that contains the string `$6$salt` to get it to generate a sha-512 crypt e.g.

```
char *salt = "$6$pt4wu5ns";
char *password = "muppet show";

printf("%s\n", crypt(password, salt));
```

Answer (score -3):

Here's a website on how to implement the sha1 algorithm.

http://bradconte.com/sha1_c

Normally I would describe the algorithm, but really there;s nothing to it, just mix up the bits with a complex series of adds and shifts. The tricky bit is getting it to exactly conform to everyone else;s sha1 code.